# LWUIT Label: Creating a Custom Label

Tags: java, java-me, label, paint, lwuit

I am trying to create a custom `Label`. I want to do something like markups on an `Image`
depending on what the user enters. I really don't know how to do it but I hope that you will know what I am trying to achieve here. What is the proper way to derive the `Label` class? This is my code.

```
class CustomLabel extends Label
{
   List paths;
   Image image;
   public CustomLabel(Image img,List paths)
   {
     this.image = img;
     this.paths = paths;
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
     g.setColor(0x000000);
     for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) 
     {
        Path path = (Path)paths.getModel().getItemAt(i);
        int firstLocX = path.discoveredNode.getX();
        int firstLocY = path.discoveredNode.getY();
        int secondLocX = path.nodeDiscovered.getX();
        int secondLocY = path.nodeDiscovered.getY();
        g.drawLine(firstLocX, firstLocY, secondLocX, secondLocY);
     }
     g.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
     UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel().drawLabel(g, this);
   }
}
```

I hope you can help me with this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel().drawLabel(g, this);`

Since you want your drawing to appear on top you want the label to draw first and then have your code so the first line in the `paint` method should be `super.paint(g)` which will take care of that.

Your call to drawImage draws it at 0,0 which is always wrong. You should position drawing based on `getX()` and `getY()`.

Having said that I don't see anything that warrants subclassing. If you just want to draw an emblem why not create a style that has an aligned image in its background with the given emblem. Then just conditionally assign the right UIID to the label.